# How do I write a query that includes users that aren't in the table at all?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I currently have this query set up:

```
SELECT age, hobbies, country
FROM profile
INNER JOIN matches
ON profiel.usernumber = matches.user1
WHERE age BETWEEN ? and ?
AND usernumber != ?
AND usernumber NOT IN (SELECT user2 FROM matches WHERE matches.user1 = ?)
```

FYI:
I'm using two tables.
Table "profile" has all the user info we need (age, hobbies, etc.).
Table "matches" has two user numbers of users that matched. Only if you click the "match" button you get inserted into the "matches" table with your user number and your match.

The problem:
The current query only selects users that are in the table "matches" but aren't matched with you. I also want the users that aren't matched at all (and thus aren't in the matches table)

I've tried multiple options with AND or OR but I haven't figured anything out myself. I'm new to coding so I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Ude `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: are the age between/usernumber != criteria supposed to apply to the users that didn't match?  are you trying to select age/hobbies/country for those users or for the current user?

Comment: edit your question to show (as text, not images) your schema (output of `show create table profile;` and `show create table matches;`), insert statements for sample data, and desired results for that sample data.

Comment: I should have clarified. The ? and ? for BETWEEN are the age of the current user (-5 and +5 but that's written in the JS code). The ? for the usernumber is the usernumber of the current user. We are trying to select the age hobbies and country for users that have not matched with the current user.

Comment: Barman your comment worked, if you can post it as answer I can select it as the right one :)

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` only show records that exists on both tables. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT age, hobbies, country
FROM profile
LEFT JOIN matches ON profiel.usernumber = matches.user1
```